# Is the SMTP virtual server deprecated in IIS 7?

Tags: iis, smtp

It seems that in IIS 7 (7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2) the SMTP virtual server is a second-class citizen, only being configurable through the IIS 6.0 compatibility-mode management tool. This arrangement leads me to wonder whether the SMTP virtual server is deprecated, or otherwise "on it's way out".

Is this accurate? Is the SMTP virtual server shipped with IIS being phased out? Is there a replacement on its way in?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR from [here](http://silverlightdev.net/sending-mail-from-an-asp-net-website/): Yes, it's gone. You can install IIS 6 SMTP server, but it sucks. Far better to use something like [hMailServer which is free and works great](http://www.hmailserver.com/).

Comment: Stupid link restrictions. Continued:

By the way, [you can use ASP.Net to send email through GMail's SMTP server](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/send-email-using-gmail-in-aspnet.html). Fair warning, I haven't verified that article; my university campus blocks the SMTPS port (587).

Comment: I'm interested in incoming mail, not outgoing. Further, your source is hardly authoritative.

Comment: I finally decided to downvote your answer, because a) the SMTP server is clearly not "gone"; b) saying it "sucks" is not helpful at all, and c) I'm not asking for third-party software recommendations, I'm asking if Microsoft has plans to replace the MTA (yes, MTA, not mail server).

Comment: **None** of this was my opinion, if that wasn't clear enough. I was just giving you the TL;DR from a relevant source I found at the time.

I haven't been able to find anything to even _hint_ at the possibility of receiving incoming mail with IIS 7. As I don't work at Microsoft, I can't tell you if they plan on replacing the MTA - unless you want to pay for Exchange Server.

Comment: Now, I'm assuming that you're not asking this question just because you're curious, but because you actually require the capabilities of an MTA - sending and receiving mail.

If so, then the only responsible answer is to recommend you use third party software. I don't recommend hMailServer - that was just the TL;DR from the article - but it would seem you have to go somewhere else for that capability.

Even if you're just curious, though, someone might stumble upon this thread requiring more.

Comment: Instead of going third party, you could also create your own Windows service to listen on ports 25 and 587 and implement it yourself, but I would recommend against that. Any big third party software will hopefully have already mitigated potential problems that would arise when you [start listening on ports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751405.aspx).

Comment: You can absolutely install IIS6's SMTP "server" (MTA, really...) on newer versions of Windows, so it's not "gone" at all, just less visible.

Comment: But is there a way to receive incoming mail?

Answer (score 0):

It is recently that Microsoft started to add explicit notes to its documentation around IIS 6 SMTP service in recent Windows releases (IIS 8 and above) that deprecating this component for good,

> The IIS SMTP Virtual Server Component that is mentioned in this article is part of IIS 6.0, the support for which has ended with the support of [Windows Server 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/810). To relay emails to Office 365, use one of the supported versions of Exchange Server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above#note

So literally speaking, you shouldn't use SMTP service after July 14, 2015 (end of life date for Windows Server 2003).