# Local SMTP Server

Tags: email, iis, smtp, iis-7.5

I used IIS5.1 prior with the Virtual SMTP Server to send some internal mail. However, we've been upgraded to IIS7.5 and there is no SMTP Server for some reason Microsoft doesn't have a fit explanation for. Is there a comparable local SMTP Server that I could use (I only need send-only, not a full mail server, if that makes a difference)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you can still use IIS6 SMTP server on IIS7.5, or you can use a free smtp server alternative as listed below.

**IIS6 SMTP**:

[Is the SMTP virtual server deprecated in IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429747/is-the-smtp-virtual-server-deprecated-in-iis-7)

http://www.chrislazari.com/2011/04/iis-75-installing-smtp-service-securing.html

http://forums.iis.net/p/1157046/1901343.aspx

Popular alternatives:

**MailEnable** http://www.mailenable.com/standard_edition.asp

**SmarterMail** http://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/mail-server-software.aspx

**hMailServer** http://www.hmailserver.com/

Search for more: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20mail%20servers%20free%20smtpo&aq=f&oq=windows%20mail%20servers%20free%20smtpo&aqs=chrome.0.57j0.4930j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=windows%20mail%20servers%20free%20smtp&oq=windows%20mail%20servers%20free%20smtp&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30.1484.1484.0.1699.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.NVi3B7vK98k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.eWU&fp=9610ee3d36cde05&biw=1280&bih=939)

Comment: Well I'll upvote. I'm reading through the links now, and it looks like they speak to what I"m looking for.

Comment: It is possible to keep using IIS6 SMTP virtual server as you are used to, but these alternatives such as MailEnable offer a stand-alone SMTP server which I've always found to be 1) more reliable than IIS and 2) easier to manage/troubleshoot than IIS. You could always use a remote SMTP server if thats ok.

Comment: We have pretty aggressive firewalls, and I think that's causing an issue. I tried hMailServer, but I couldn't get my code to send mail. It worked with IIS5.1, don't know why.

Comment: Have to make sure the SMTP service is working (`netstat -ano | find ":25"` will show if a process is listening on port 25) and if that is working and you aren't getting errors then check for outbound firewall filtering but that is rare. I've seen anti-virus block outbound port 25 more often than firewalls.